# Ubuntu 14.04 screen stays black or purple when you start

Tags: 14.04, wine, synaptic

lo que pasa es que hace un tiempo instalé Ubuntu 14.04 en inicio dual con Windows 8.1 en mi pc (Hp Pavilion AMD A8) y corría normal pero hace un momento necesita usar wine pero me di cuenta que no había instalado bien, entonces abrí synaptic y decía que tenía ficheros rotos, entonces le di desinstalar y dijo que debía desintalar unos ficheros, actualizar otros e instalar otros más, y comenzó. Pero en un momento se cayó mi internet por wifi y el proceso se trabó, traté de darle cancelar pero no me dejó, entonces le di apagar y bueno, apagó, pero al momento de volverlo a iniciar se queda en la pantalla morada o en la negra ¿qué puedo hacer para arreglarlo? 
Gracias de antemano.

---

Rough Translation:

what happens is that some time ago I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot with Windows 8.1 on my pc (HP Pavilion AMD A8) and was running normally but just now need to use wine but I realized I had not installed well, then I opened synaptic and he said he had broken files, then gave uninstall and said I should uninstall some files, update other and install others, and began. But at one point my internet fell by wifi and the process is stuck, I tried to give cancel but would not let me, so I gave him off and good extinguished, but when you restart it stays on the home screen or black what can I do to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be aware that this site is English-based, and questions should be in English.  This also applies to comments, so that everyone can follow what you are trying to say.  All comments on here have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42221/discussion-on-question-by-jordi-neil-sanchez-ubuntu-14-04-se-queda-en-pantalla-n), as well, as comments are not for extended discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In English:

Upgrade to 16.04.  Since you said in chat that you don't have any data on that partition anyhow, I recommend downloading the ISO for Ubuntu 16.04LTS, and burning it either to a DVD, CD or USB stick.  Since you had some concerns about AMD hardware, try running it live, and if it works, do a full install.  Make sure you only format your "ext4" partition and the "swap", as your Windows will be on a "fat" or "ntfs" partition.

---

## En español:

Actualizar a 16.04. Puesto que usted dijo en el chat que usted no tiene todos los datos de esa partición, recomiendo la descarga de la ISO para Ubuntu 16.04LTS, y su instalación, ya sea en un DVD, CD o una memoria USB. Desde que tenía algunas preocupaciones acerca del hardware de AMD, intenta ejecutarlo en vivo, y si funciona, hacer una instalación completa. Asegúrese de que sólo formato a la partición "ext4" y el "intercambio", como su Windows será en una "fat", "fat16", "fat32", o partición "NTFS".